# another user copied my answer and tell OP that she has already updated answer

Tags: discussion

Today I just give the answer to this question

[How to add css only for checkout page of rwd theme in Magento 1.9.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196993/how-to-add-css-only-for-checkout-page-of-rwd-theme-in-magento-1-9-0)

and same time other user

https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/52030/rita-jose

Also, gives her answer in a different way

But when she show my answer accepted instead of her

she update her answer and tell to OP that she has already updated her answer and force OP to accept her answer

here is her update history

https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/196995/revisions

Is this kind of behavior allowed?

Here is here chat screenshot with that user

[image]

Comment: thanks for posting this question :)

Comment: @piyush I saw that you also give answer to that question but you deleted your answer after knowing real problem,I appriciate your behaviour

Comment: @Piyush is this kind of things happened with you ??

Comment: Yes I have faced this too, as I have mentioned in my comment on Amit's answer , here is the link to answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176303/20064

Comment: She reverted these changes and now the accepted answer is just wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Murtaza,

we cannot prove that **she is copied your code logically but as per human behavior as,it is truly indicated that she was copied code**.

Because of she's code has mistake a `<<checkout_onepage_index> translate="label">` ,So should not run.

But it is bad that **Abhilash Narayan** has accepted  without worked.
As this **an user call so , we  did not  stop him to accept the answer**.

**In case,  i guess ,we can  only **do down vote**  to  rite rose answer**.

***Also upvote  correct answer.***

As suggestion,Murtuza Zabuawala donot mind this type work from other user.
You will see lot time.

Please carry on your  good answer to mse

Comment: Thank you bro for supporting me, As @Abhilesh has accepted my answer first and then Rita show that then she updated and you can see by expanding chat Abhilesh tell her that my answer worked for him , then she edited her answer according to my answer, and even she does not stop here and tell abhilesh that she has already updated her answer even before me you can see that comment in screenshot, right now she has deleted that comment

Comment: Thank you Bro, she realize her mistake and updated her answer. Thank you for your supprot

Comment: same happened with me , a user copied my answer just after 20-30 minutes of my post, that user just changed the variable names in his answer. After answer he just keep commenting on OP's question so his answer can be noticed first and at last OP accepted his answer. I flagged that answer for moderator intervention and was marked helpful, but no action was taken.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at this from 2 different aspects.

1. The legal one: Yep it's legal. A user can edit his/her answer whenever he/she wants as long as the terms and conditions are followed. If there are clear signs of plagiarism then there is a problem, but in this case your answer was a short one and It's not really obvious that the other user copied your content. There are significant differences between the 2 answers. Also one user can accept any answer without the need to explain the choice.
2. The moral one: Is this moral? Not really, but there no destructive actions can be taken against the accepted answer just for that.  All you can do is leave a comment under the other answer saying that this is not moral. Just make sure you keep it clean.

Comment: Yes, marius, i am agree with your point

Comment: @Marius I also know that we can not take any destructive action against her, but I just want to warn her so that she doesn't do this kind of things with others

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry that you feel bad for such an immoral action. But we cannot do anything in this situation against the answerer.

As a community member, you should not feel bad now because you have 8k points in the site which itself shows your positive inputs to the community. But Rita is a starter and we should appreciate her efforts to answer the question.

Here the "immoral" behavior came from the OP in my opinion. He resolved his issue from your answer and hence accepted it. Then he just gives credits to Rita's answer. There may be multiple reasons for that. It may be due to:

- Rita may be his friend.
- He felt that Rita's answer is more descriptive than yours and thought that answer is better than yours (in later stage).
- etc etc.

As you can see, reasons are plenty. Suppose the second one is OP's reason to accept her answer, does it become immoral? It's a question that we need to ask ourself.

The point here is, you are doing well here and you should always try to be a good community member. Good community member always improves the content of this site and always have a positive approach to any action. A good community member also encourages other community members for their contribution.

If they did anything wrong or immoral, then you should guide them and tell them through a comment that it is not what we expect from a community behavior.

We are not here to teach others morality, but help each other and improve the content of this site.

So emotions aside... a positive and a helping mentality beside. :)

Comment: Thank you bro , I don't have any question to OP as you can see I haven't mentioned that he has done this and anything like that because at that time OP has just 6 reputations so it's understandable he is quite new, but I have problem with Rita as she copied the things and even after she lies to OP

Answer (score 3):

Give answer and expect nothing that my mote on **MSE**. I recommend same to you. If someone copy your answer let them copy. Gaining some extra **FAKE POINT** does not make them good developer. In the end it is OP choice which answer they accept. Don't take thing seriously on **MSE**. I think the single **comment** was enough for this kind of behavior or directly contact with **MOD**.